# Custom order status background button color in Woocommerce 3.3 admin order list

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

With the new woo orders screen, the old color status icons are now gone and replaced with a large status button with a colored background.

Processing is green, Completed is blue, Cancelled is grey etc.

I have a custom order status in woocommerce orders called: In Progress. Custom order statuses seem to also be given just a default grey color background. I would like to assign a color background to my custom order status. I have tried to find a code snippet in order to do this, but have had no luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set CSS color and background color to your custom order status displayed in admin order list this way:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'styling_admin_order_list' );
function styling_admin_order_list() {
    global $pagenow, $post;

    if( $pagenow != 'edit.php') return; // Exit
    if( get_post_type($post->ID) != 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit

    // HERE we set your custom status
    $order_status = 'Dispatched'; // <==== HERE
    ?>
    <style>
        .order-status.status-<?php echo sanitize_title( $order_status ); ?> {
            background: #d7f8a7;
            color: #0c942b;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Perfect! -Thank you so much !

Comment: @yatgirl Updated the code here… [see my answer in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49593241/woocommerce-sales-reports-include-custom-order-status/49593606#49593606) for explanations… sorry :)

Comment: I am wondering how I could adapt this code so that it could also be used with  Custom Statuses of the WooCommerce Order Status Manager

Comment: It is possible to do the same for the frontend my-account> orders.php page ?