# Include Custom Order Status in Woocommerce Orders sales reports

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, report, orders

I have a custom order status - In Progress.  The code I have for it is below.  It works great - but the orders with this custom order status are not being included in the standard Woo Sales Reports or the Woocommerce Status Dashboard Widget.

Could someone please help me out and take a look and see how I can add to this snippet below so that the $ from this custom order status 'In Progress' are reflected in the Woo Sales Report $.

```
// 1 New order status AFTER woo 2.2 IN PROGRESS
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_new_order_statuses' );
function register_my_new_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-in-progress', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'In Progress', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'In Progress <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'In Progress<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'my_new_wc_order_statuses' );
// Register in wc_order_statuses.
function my_new_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-in-progress'] = _x( 'In Progress', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

/*
 * 2 CHANGE STATUSES ORDER IN DROPDOWN LIST
 * @param array $wc_statuses_arr Array of all order statuses on the website
 */
function change_statuses_order( $wc_statuses_arr ){

    $new_statuses_arr = array(
        'wc-processing' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-processing'], // 1
        'wc-in-progress' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-in-progress'], // 2      
        'wc-completed' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-completed'], // 3
        'wc-cancelled' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-cancelled'], // 4
        'wc-refunded' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-refunded'], // 5
        'wc-failed' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-failed'], // 6
        'wc-pending' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-pending'], // 7
        'wc-on-hold' => $wc_statuses_arr['wc-on-hold'] // 8
    );

    return $new_statuses_arr;
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'change_statuses_order' );

/** 3 ADD COLOR TO IN PROGRESS BUTTON **/

add_action('admin_head', 'styling_admin_order_list' );
function styling_admin_order_list() {
    global $pagenow;
    if( $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order' && $pagenow == 'edit.php'):

    // HERE below set your custom status
    $order_status = 'In Progress'; // <==== HERE
    ?>
    <style>
        .order-status.status-<?php echo sanitize_title( $order_status ); ?> {
            background: #cc0099;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following hooked function, that will add your "custom status" to Orders reports:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', 'include_custom_order_status_to_reports', 20, 1 );
function include_custom_order_status_to_reports( $statuses ){
    // Adding the custom order status to the 3 default woocommerce order statuses
    return array( 'processing', 'in-progress', 'completed', 'on-hold' );
}
```

`Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).` Tested and works.

---

There is a generated error in your 3rd function related to `$_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order'`… Instead you can chnage it this way:

```
// 3. ADD COLOR TO IN PROGRESS BUTTON
add_action('admin_head', 'styling_admin_order_list' );
function styling_admin_order_list() {
    global $pagenow, $post;

    if( $pagenow != 'edit.php') return; // Exit
    if( get_post_type($post->ID) != 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit

    // HERE below set your custom status
    $order_status = 'In Progress'; // <==== HERE
    ?>
    <style>
        .order-status.status-<?php echo sanitize_title( $order_status ); ?> {
            background: #cc0099;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

It will avoid this small error as `post_type` is not in the URL of order edit pages *(I know is my fault as this was the code of one of my answers)*…

Comment: Excellent !  It works perfectly - and the revision to the #3 code is also great - thanks so much - you have really helped me improve my store, my process and my reporting with these 2 snippets - I am very grateful !

Comment: @yatgirl Welcome… You can even enable your custom status in backend order list too [in the bulk action select field](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+bulk_actions-edit-shop_order)

Comment: The correction to the 3rd function you gave me is causing a php error in my php error log. in particular the line :   if( get_post_type($post->ID) != 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit.  The error in my log is PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(469) : eval()'d code on line 48.  I am wondering if there is some correction I can make to the code in order to stop the error. It supposedly is because of the -> @LoicTheAztec