# Does anybody know how to change the color depending on stringname?

Tags: php, css, if-statement, woocommerce

I try to change the color of an order-status-span-element to color red, if the order status is "Pending payment". 
As soon as the status changes to "completed", the span text color should switch to green.

Here is the clean div code:

```
<div class="order-status">
        <span>Order Status</span>
        <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
        <?php echo '<span id="order-status-value">' . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) . '<span>'; ?>

    </div>
```

I tried to insert a proper if-statement, but I don't know which function or variable I need to insert. 
This is the snippet is only a part of my orders.php ->(.../my-account/orders).

```
<div class="order-status">
    <span>Order Status</span>
    <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
    <?php echo '<span id="order-status-value">' . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) . '<span>';
        if ( strcasecmp( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) == 0 ) ) :
                echo "The if statement works!";
        ?>      
                <style type="text/css">
                    #order-status-value {
                        color: green;
                    }
                </style>
        <?php 
        else: 
        ?>
                <style type="text/css">
                    #order-status-value {
                        color: red;
                    }
                </style>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code doesn't work.

Comment: In back or front office ?

Comment: Hello, on front end - the orders page, which the user can see (.../my-account/orders).

Comment: there is no `if` in this code...

Comment: @Berto99 on line 5 there is an if statement. I just didn't add an "else" to complete it.

Comment: To help spot issues in the future, you can also add this to the top of your scripts during development: `ini_set('display_startup_errors', true); ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` ... it would have alerted you to the missing `)` in your `if`

Comment: check this tips [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333542/custom-order-status-background-button-color-in-woocommerce-3-3-admin-order-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333542/custom-order-status-background-button-color-in-woocommerce-3-3-admin-order-list)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "style" HTML attribute to change the color :

```
<?php

    $is_green = wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status()) == 0;
        
    echo '<span id="order-status-value" ' 
    . ($is_green ? 'style="color:green"' : '')
    . '>' 
    . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) 
    . '<span>';
```

Comment: `unsafe-inline` comes to mind ... but this definitely would solve his current crisis.

Comment: You're right @IncredibleHat. Using class attribut should be a better choice.

Comment: But it kind of depends, most sites are fine without going down the hell of CSP ;-)

Comment: My biggest issue is that there is an error on line 55 - that one with the if-statement.
But your solutions seem to be much better :)
"wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status()" I just tried, but this must be incorrect.

Comment: In your posted code, you're missing the last closing parenthesis : ` if ( strcasecmp( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) == 0 )) :`. And also in my code. I've updated it. But removed strcasecmp(). Need 2 parameters.

Comment: I created a solution for this issue.
I'd like to post it, but it seems to be not possible to post a solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use at the moment - this one works perfectly.

```
<div class="order-status">
            <span>Order Status</span>
            <?php           
            elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) :
                $order_color_check = $order->get_status();  
                if($order_color_check=="completed") :
                    echo '<span class="order-status-value" style="color: green;">' . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) . '</span>';
                    
                else :
                    echo '<span class="order-status-value" style="color: red;">' . esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ) . '</span>';
                endif; ?>
        </div>
```