# Set color of custom order status in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I "made" a plugin for Woocommerce that adds an extra order status.
I did not do the coding myself, I found it on the internet.
The plugin contains:

I combined the two scripts, but the colour off the button does not work. Anyone an idea for me?

```
function wpblog_wc_register_post_statuses() {
register_post_status( 'wc-shipping-progress', array(
    'label' => _x( 'In productie', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
    'public' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
    'label_count' => _n_noop( 'Approved (%s)', 'Approved (%s)', 'text_domain' )
) );
}

add_filter( 'init', 'wpblog_wc_register_post_statuses' );

function wpblog_wc_add_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipping-progress'] = _x( 'In productie', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
return $order_statuses;
}

add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'wpblog_wc_add_order_statuses' );

add_action('admin_head', 'styling_admin_order_list' );
function styling_admin_order_list() {
global $pagenow, $post;

if( $pagenow != 'edit.php') return; // Exit
if( get_post_type($post->ID) != 'shop_order' ) return; // Exit

// HERE we set your custom status
$order_status = 'In productie'; // <==== HERE
?>
<style>
    .order-status.status-<?php echo sanitize_title( $order_status ); ?> {
        background: #d7f8a7;
        color: #0c942b;
    }
</style>
<?php
}
```

This works! But the background color of the new status is default gray.

Does anyone want to help me add some css to the code to give a nice bg color?

Comment: I believe this answers your question [Custom order status background button color in Woocommerce 3.3 admin order list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333542/custom-order-status-background-button-color-in-woocommerce-3-3-admin-order-list)

Comment: That is an old code for older Woocommerce versions. It doesn't apply to current code.

Comment: I just tested this in WooCommerce 4.6.2 along with your code and it still works **perfectly**. You have to **replace** `// HERE we set your custom status $order_status = 'Dispatched';` **with** `$order_status = 'shipping-progress'`

Comment: What do you mean along with my code. Did you combine both codes?
I can imagine that would work, yet I don't know how to combine them. 
Maybe you can give me a cope example?

Comment: I updated the question, with the two codes combined. But still the color does not work. Can anyone please assist me?